# Jquery Masonry Seamless Responsive Image Grid

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, responsive-design, jquery-masonry

I'm looking to create a seamless (no gutters) fullscreen image grid using jquery masonry, where the images are fully responsive and are of varying widths. I've found a couple other starting points out there, but it's proving to be quite difficult for my amount of jquery knowledge.

This is what I'm going for:
http://future.thefutureforward.com/~cycles/assets/images/HUB0002_dAutremont_4WEB.jpg

And this is what I have so far:
http://future.thefutureforward.com/~cycles/archive-test-fluid.html

HTML (just a portion):

```
<div id="masonry-container">  
    <div class="box nav-container">
        <div id="bumble-bee-sub"><a href="[[~1]]"><img src="assets/img/bumble_bee.png" alt="Cycles d'Autremont" title="Cycles d'Autremont" /></a></div>
        <ul id="nav-masonry">
            <li><a href="#">Featured</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="assets/images/archive-thumbs/one.jpg" alt="" title="" />
            <span class="bike-name"><span>Bicycle #001</span></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="assets/images/archive-thumbs/two.jpg" alt="" title="" /> 
        <span class="bike-name"><span>Bicycle #002</span></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="assets/images/archive-thumbs/three.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <span class="bike-name"><span>Bicycle #003</span></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS for each "box":

```
.box{
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
max-width: 33.3%; /* since we're going for three across... */
}
.box img {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

And here's the jQuery that's doing most the heavy-lifting:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var CollManag = (function() {
            var $ctCollContainer = $('#masonry-container'),
            collCnt = 1,
            init = function() {
                changeColCnt();
                initEvents();
                initPlugins();
            },
            changeColCnt = function() {
                var w_w = $(window).width();
                if( w_w <= 600 ) n = 2;
                else n = 3;
            },
            initEvents = function() {
                $(window).on( 'smartresize.CollManag', function( event ) {
                    changeColCnt();
                });
            },
            initPlugins = function() {
                $ctCollContainer.imagesLoaded( function(){
                    $ctCollContainer.masonry({
                        itemSelector : '.box',
                        columnWidth : function( containerWidth ) {
                            return containerWidth / n;
                        },
                        isAnimated : true,
                        animationOptions: {
                            duration: 300
                        }
                    });
                });
            };
            return { init: init };
        })();
        CollManag.init();
    });
```

It's getting there, but at certain widths it's not filling all of the gaps properly, and smaller screen sizes need some work. If anyone has any tips or thoughts on how to improve this, that would be amazing.

Comment: Probably wrong suggestion, but have you considered http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin as alternative? Some of the gaps (hard to see in your sandbox because of the black background) are due to the fact that your Isotope items have sometimes a width of less than one column, therefore a gap is inevitable, unless you use a matching modularity in terms of Isotope item size. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11701171/963514 (with fiddle) or http://stackoverflow.com/a/11814339/963514

Comment: thanks for the thoughts, @Systembolaget. that example for wookmark doesn't show items of variable widths, so I'm wondering if it's worth trying or not. Based on your experience, do you think I would be better off trying isotope? I didn't think I needed it since I'm not doing any filtering, but perhaps it offers something that would help...and I'll make my BG white so the gaps are easier to recognize.

Comment: also, here's a version with static widths (which I'm not against) - http://future.thefutureforward.com/~cycles/archives/ - still having issues. your fiddle with isotope and fixed width/height seemed better than this attempt - do you think copying your fiddle and setting specific widths/height for the different sizes will yield better results? I'm just not sure, since I"ve got 4 different sized boxes going...

Comment: Added "answer" below. Think about the sizes (relation of items) in terms of if you can pull off your design with less randomly sized "blocks".

Answer (score 4):

Voids in Isotope layouts can occur, because the Isotope items appear in a certain order (top down) in the DOM and - if there are items spanning two columns or three, or if there are items not conforming to the column width - therefore want to rearrage in that original order, when the browser is resized. This can be [**seen here**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/relayout.html) or [**here (with jsfiddle)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11701171/963514) when the browser window is resized sufficiently - even such strict conformity can result in some voids at certain browser sizes. Shuffling could result in an optimal fit, but not necessarily so.

One could use sorting to order the items; for that to work, they must conform to width and height multiples of one item (with appropriate margins applied). With Isotope, you have Masonry plus much more functionality while it is similarly easy to implement. Best is to think about what the layout should do for the viewer, maybe on paper first, then mock-up an undesigned sandbox, keeping the modularity issue in mind.

**UPDATE** If you examine your sandbox with Google Chrome's devtools, you'll see that

1. your nav-container has no size set; it's size x=426/y=469px only depends on its content; you should set a size in CSS that conforms to the sizing scheme of your other items which, if you look the smallest common divisor, is x=240px (240(1), 480(2), 720(3)/y=120px (240(2), 360(3), 720(6)).
2. like i mentioned above, you have elements spanning multiple columns and rows; therefore at certain browser window sizes, voids will be inevitable. If you select black as #isotope-container background in the end, this will be less noticeable, as black is your bike images background colour.
3. don't know how that #twenty-seventh-letter interferes, but see [the changed jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9T2ab/)
   how to achieve a little bit of bleed on the right before Isotope triggers layouting. But, because of layouting (Masonry, Isotope), which is the whole purpose here, you can not have bleed at all sizes - for that, you'd need to code boxes with fluid widths also, which can be done with some extra effort.

Comment: thanks for the isotope example - I'll think I'll give that a try. I'm okay with some spacing, just looking to minimize it if possible (which that demo does a good job with). I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you have no margin on your elements, they'll butt right up against each other, see another example with code http://jsfiddle.net/zewkG/20/

Comment: using isotope, it looks much better - http://future.thefutureforward.com/~cycles/archive-test-isotope.html. I've still got a space issue on the side, and occasionally within boxes, but it's an improvement. any thoughts on getting it to bleed to the right edge at all window sizes?

Comment: Updated answer with more explanations and jsfiddle. From that, it's easy to figure it all out.

Comment: Thanks so much @Systembolaget. I specified the width on the nav container at some point...didn't realize it had been lost. And interesting thought on the negative right margin of the container. Certainly helps to eliminate the width of the space at the right. In terms of creating fluid width boxes, that has been the single largest obstacle with this whole thing. I've tried using the fluid/responsive isotope example here, but it's all sorts of whacked - http://future.thefutureforward.com/~cycles/archive-test-isotope-fluid.html. All my percentages seem right... any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: You may want to look at the source code of http://vogtjosh.com/selectors/ and then read https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/28 before you decide to jump ahead and go for the fluid/responsive approach. Start simple - then enhance. Maybe you'll implement Isotope centered Masonry first, because that's fairly straightforward, and then you can get into some heavy coding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15813/discussion-between-nickff-and-systembolaget)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with fluid/responsive layouts, boxes of varying widths, and isotope/masonry appears to be a bug. If your item widths equal up to the full width of the browser window but are in decimal pixel values, there are problems.

What I ended up doing was setting three variable width columns at 19.5%, 39.5%, and 59.5% respectively. This fixed the random gap issue I was experiencing earlier (though it did introduce gutters which I'm not too stoked on).

Here it is functioning:
http://cyclesdautremont.com/blog/

For more information on this bug (and hopefully a fix one day), check out the isotope github issue dedicated to it:
https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/222